# Pycharm indexing in remote interpreter

Tags: pycharm

I'm using a remote interpreter. When open a new project, pycharm keeps indexing on a local copy of old remote files, which I don't need. So how can I set the indexing correctly? The local copy isn't under my current project folder, but under some strange direction, as `C:\Users\name\AppData\...\Pycharm\remote_sources\old_data_files`; while my local project files is under `D:\projects\`.